# Write CSV file with two columns in R loop (append)

Tags: r, csv

I have some other complex script which is working fine, except for giving trouble in writing to a csv file. Let's say here as an example that I want k and j here to be present in 20 rows, k being in one column and j being in the second.

```
for (i in 1:20)
{
    k = i+2;
    j = i+20;
    m= data.frame(k,j)
    write.csv(m,file="Dummy.csv",append=TRUE)
    print(m)
}
```

The problem with this is, **it is writing only the final value of m into the csv, even when the append is set to TRUE**

And my question here is, **do I need to make 'm' as a dataframe, matrix or a vector?**

(Consider k and j to be particular changing text strings, which I am trying to wite in a CSV extracting from a corpus)

The following is the output of the CSV file:

"","k","j"
"1",22,40

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `append = TRUE` with `write.csv`. The idea is that it should be hard to mess up `write.csv` and do something you don't want to.

You can use it with `write.table`, giving this solution:

```
for (i in 1:20)
{
  k = i+2;
  j = i+20;
  m = data.frame(k,j)
  write.table(m, file="Dummy.csv",
              append=TRUE,
              col.names = FALSE,
              sep = ',')
  print(m)
}
```

Notice you have the miss out column names otherwise you get column names added in every iteration of the loop.

But, a better idea would be to build up the dataframe in parts and write it to a csv at the end.

```
m <- data.frame(NULL)
for (i in 1:20)
{
  k <- i+2;
  j <- i+20;
  m <- rbind(m, data.frame(k,j))
}

write.csv(m, file="Dummy2.csv")
```

Comment: I got the idea. +1 for building the dataframe in parts. Thanks

Comment: I would also assume that the second version is faster since I/O operations are usually slow in R (and elsewhere).

Comment: I'm not so sure. R is also incredibly inefficient when interacting with a dataframe created outside of a for loop. If your dataframes grow large or for many iterations, the former is likely faster and more predictable.